# Как в JS получить только что созданные dom элементы?

Tags: javascript, html

Я ещё совсем совсем новичок, так что вопросы пока соответствующие.

Суть такая: на страничке есть пустой input и кнопка "+", при нажатии на которую создаётся ещё один input. Также есть кнопка "расчёт", при нажатии на которую js должен собрать все инпуты в массив и работать с ним. Но js не видит вновь созданные инпуты. В массив попадает только один, имеющийся по умолчанию на момент загрузки страницы.
Как решить эту проблему?

Мой код, если нужно:

```js
function fff() {
 let a = document.querySelector('#aaa');
 let i = document.createElement('input');
 let br = document.createElement('br');
 i.type = 'text';
 i.className = 'input';
 a.before(br, i, br);
}

function sss() {
let mass01 = document.querySelectorAll('#aaa input');
console.log(mass01);
}
```

```html
<div id='aaa'>
  <input type="text" class="input">
<div>
<button id="addinput" onclick="fff()">+</button>
<button onclick="sss()">Расчёт</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function fff() {
  const inp = document.querySelector('#aaa .input:last-of-type');
  inp.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br><input class="input">'); 
}

function sss() {
  let mass01 = document.querySelectorAll('#aaa .input');
  console.log(mass01);
}
```

```html
<div id="aaa">
  <input class="input">
  <div>
    <button id="addinput" onclick="fff()">+</button>
    <button onclick="sss()">Расчёт</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Значение атрибута `type` у инпутов по-умолчанию `text`, поэтому  его можно не указывать явно.

---

MDN:
[Псевдокласс :last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)
[Метод insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `a.before()` который вставляет **ПЕРЕД** элементом используйте `a.append()` который вставляет **В** елемент

```js
function fff() {
  let a = document.querySelector('#aaa');
  let i = document.createElement('input');
  let br = document.createElement('br');
  i.type = 'text';
  i.className = 'input';
  a.append(br, i, br);
}

function sss() {
  let mass01 = document.querySelectorAll('#aaa input');
  console.log(mass01);
}
```

```html
<div id='aaa'>
  <input type="text" class="input">
</div>
<button id="addinput" onclick="fff()">+</button>
<button onclick="sss()">Расчёт</button>
```

Comment: да, действительно. большое спасибо!